# how do i create a proper in statement with sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

****Edited, I forgot my teacher changed the tables a little, the primary key for both author and bookauthor is author_id and only author has ssn, not bookauthor****

My professor has given us a practice assignment for the IN statement for mysql and I can not, for the life of me, understand how to use the in statement and it is driving me crazy.

This is his question: 
**"Using a subquery, list the author's names for all books that have more than one author."**

there is a database system with four tables, but really we only need two I think but i will put three down anyways

**book** table with
isbn (primary), title, type, pub_id, price, advance, ytd_sales, pub_date

**bookauthor** table(which is in between book and author) with, author_id(primary), isbn, author_order, royaltyshare

**author** table with, author_id(primary), ssn, lastname, firstname, phone, address, city, state, zip

the best I could come up with is

```
select lastname, firstname, isbn
from author where isbn in
(select isbn
from bookauthor
having count(author_id) > 1)
```

but it isn't working, and honestly, i don't really understand the in statement, I have read a lot of different websites, but they only seem to give basic info and it's driving me crazy. how does it work?

Comment: what's the error are you getting?

Comment: I dislike this kind of question, because of course, a subquery (and particularly one using IN) is neither necessary nor appropriate in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more simply written as a `JOIN` with a derived table (subquery) which counts the authors for each book:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM author a
JOIN bookauthor ba ON ba.author_id = a.author_id
JOIN (SELECT isbn
      FROM bookauthor
      GROUP BY isbn
      HAVING COUNT(author_id) > 0) c ON c.isbn = ba.isbn
```

If you have to use `IN`, you can just replace the last `JOIN` with a `WHERE ... IN` expression:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM author a
JOIN bookauthor ba ON ba.author_id = a.author_id
WHERE ba.isbn IN (SELECT isbn
                  FROM bookauthor
                  GROUP BY isbn
                  HAVING COUNT(author_id) > 0)
```

The `IN` expression works by comparing each `ba.isbn` value with the list of `isbn` values returned by the subquery - in this case, all those with more than one author. If `ba.isbn` is in this list, the row is displayed.

Comment: @Thewanderingstudent just noticed your changes to the question; I've updated my answer to match.